# I want to read from server a list of CV ( one Cv for each user )

Tags: jakarta-ee

I want to read from server a list of CV ( one Cv for each user ) how to do ! ?

```
JButton btCv = new JButton("consulter CV");
    btCv.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String cvPath = "http://localhost:8383/";

            if (jnkj.getSelectedRow() != -1) {
                cvPath = cvPath
                        + (String) jnkj.getModel().getValueAt(
                                jnkj.getSelectedRow(), 1);
                cvPath = cvPath
                        + (String) jnkj.getModel().getValueAt(
                                jnkj.getSelectedRow(), 2);
                cvPath = cvPath
                        + Integer.toString((Integer) jnkj.getModel()
                                .getValueAt(jnkj.getSelectedRow(), 3))
                        + ".pdf";
                // cvPath=cvPath+"abir.pdf";
            }

            if (jnkj.getSelectedRow() != -1
                    && cvPath
                            .equals("D:/Tools/wildfly-8.1.0.Final/welcome-content/")) {
                cvPath = cvPath
                        + (String) jnkj.getModel().getValueAt(
                                jnkj.getSelectedRow(), 1);
                cvPath = cvPath
                        + (String) jnkj.getModel().getValueAt(
                                jnkj.getSelectedRow(), 2);
                cvPath = cvPath
                        + Integer.toString((Integer) jnkj.getModel()
                                .getValueAt(jnkj.getSelectedRow(), 6))
                        + ".pdf";
            }

            // cvPath=cvPath+"abir.pdf";
```

Comment: You need to explain what isn't working

Comment: I need to show the CV , when I press consulter Cv ! but it dont work ! it just show the cv when write cvPath=cvPath+"abir.pdf";

Answer (score 1):

Did you run into an exception you overlooked?!

I assume jnki is a TableModel representing values in rows & columns. Columns start at 0, not at 1.